# Was V blind in the film "V for Vendetta"?

Tags: movie, v-for-vendetta

During the film *V for Vendetta*, the character Delia Surridge recounts her experiences at Larkhill in her journal. She describes V developing abnormal abilities and kinesthesia, and when encountering V while the facility is burning to the ground, writes "...he looked at me, not with eyes - there *were* no eyes - but I know he was looking at me because I felt it."

Was V physically blind as a result of the experiments performed on him at Larkhill (or perhaps due to the fire), but somehow he compensated with his other heightened senses?

[image]

Comment: Off topic because it is Not SciFi

Comment: @dvk - There were certainly elements of sci-fi in the comic including an artificial intelligence

Comment: @DVK A dystopian future history [whose anti-hero is given advanced strength, reflexes, endurance and pain tolerance via cruel medical experiments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_for_Vendetta#V) sounds like sci-fi to me.

Comment: And I was hoping there was evidence that V used some sort of sixth sense (which would definitely be a sci-fi element) to picture the environment around him.

Answer (score 30):

### No, he isn't blind in either the film or the source comic.

Ignoring the more obvious elements (fight scenes, throwing of knives, etc) there are at least two occasions where he performs acts that would be impossible without sight:

**When he lacerates the poster**:

[image: V lacerates the poster]

**Cooking for Evey (where he flips and then catches a piece of bread in the pan)**

[image: V cooks for Evey]

In the comic book, a line in [Dr Delia's diary](http://alexpeak.com/twr/vfv/diary/) makes it clear that he can still see at the time of his escape;

> "**He looked at me.** As if I were an insect. Oh God. As if I were
>   something mounted on a slide."

And the film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/ar/book/show/5812.V_for_Vendetta) makes multiple references to V *looking at things*, for example;

> "Sutler," V told him, his masked face leaning forward over Creedy's shoulder now, **so he could see the way the mans eyes flashed.**

and

> Gasping in a deep breath, **V turned away then, surveying his night's work**: a scatter of dead bodies in a grimy, derelict Underground station that still resonated with the violence of his deeds, awash with blood and reeking with the smell of gunsmoke.

Comment: Although in the film, Delia specifically states "...he looked at me, not with eyes - **there were no eyes** - but I know he was looking at me because I felt it."

Comment: @RobertF - "There were no eyes" could easily be read as "I couldn't see his eyes" since his back was to a bright fire...

Comment: Also he watches a tv, reads a book. We can also see that he has eyes when he catches Evey why wearing balaclava.

Comment: @Yasskier Do you mean to tell me that a blind person cannot face a television or hold up a book and turn pages?

Comment: @DaveJohnson He doesn't behave like a blind person watching tv (they usually slightly tilt their heads to hear better instead facing straight) and I really fail to see why as a blind man he would pretend to read while holding a book. Ockham razor strikes again :)

Comment: "Ignoring the more obvious elements (fight scenes, throwing of knives, etc)". Some blind comic characters fight very well !

Comment: @Taladris - Indeed, and hence why they're to be ignored.

Comment: I don't understand. Why couldn't a blind character (possibly with superhuman other senses) slice a poster or flip and catch a piece of bread in a pan? The evidence mentioned in the comments seems more indicative of vision.

Comment: @sumelic - Because people make noises when they fight as well as disrupting the air. Posters don't. The same goes for cooking. The ambient noises would make it hard for him to sense where the bread was.

Answer (score 8):

Evey walks in on him in the Shadow Gallery reading a book.

Comment: We have no specific evidence that he can actually read it though

Comment: Holding a book while blind seems quite pointless though @Richard.

Comment: a screencap, or a video would go a long way here.

Comment: @yondaime008 - You do need to take into account that he's A) Trying to deceive her for much of the movie and B) As mad as a box of frogs.

Comment: @Richard fair enough !

Answer (score 5):

When he was dueling with the armor, he didn't react to Evey's presence until he looked in her direction. Hearing her like Daredevil or using some sixth sense would have already alerted him to her being there, and acting surprised would serve no purpose since she already thinks he's amazingly skilled. And collecting art would be pointless, not to mention impossibly inaccurate, if he couldn't see. He can clearly see, he puts on an act. Though I suspect he does have some extremely improved hearing and maybe a low degree of a sixth sense.